# Using password file in a bash file for mosquitto broker

Tags: linux, password-protection, mosquitto

First of all I work in Linux.

I got a .sh file and it should ask for my username and password and then use it to confirm it with the password file created with mosquitto_passwd.

I ask the password and username and store them as following.(this .sh file runs in the terminal)

```
echo give username
read username
echo give password
read password
```

I'm very new to all of this but I think that's a quite correct way of doing it. My question is how can I use these to let my program only run if both username and password match with what's in my password file. I use hashed passwords in my password file but I don't know if that makes any big difference.

The design choice isn't mine since this is a part of an exercise. We must use the internet to solve it but I just don't find anything that can help me.

Thanks a lot already

Comment: *"I'm new to all of this but I think that's a quite correct way of doing it..."* - Based on the limited information in the reading, this sounds like a bad design decision. You should probably switch to authentication tokens, like Kerberos or OAuth2.

Comment: The design decision isn't mine to make. Its an exercise I am making :/